# Disable SSL listeners in LAMP stack

Tags: 14.04, ssl, openssl, https

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server, and I've installed a LAMP stack.

However, I need to disable SSL in the LAMP stack.  How do I go about disabling the `ssl` functionality?

Comment: Question: how did you enable it? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

LAMP is just a fancy way of saying "Linux Apache / MySQL / PHP" bundle, so Apache's the one you have to work with.

This should help/work:

```
sudo a2dismod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: does not work .

Comment: sudo: a2dismod: command not found

Comment: @stevGates how did you install your LAMP stack initially?  Because `a2dismod` is a *critical* Apache tool, if it's missing, you've got a bigger problem.